# What is an Emacs- and org-friendly "command character" for GNU Screen?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings

The default "command character" for GNU-screen is `C-a`, which collides with the default key combination for `move-beginning-of-line` in Emacs, and for the analogous command of many other interfaces.

It is difficult to find an alternative command character for GNU-screen that does not collide with some common Emacs binding.  And for users of org-mode the problem is considerably worse.

I figure that there must be enough users of both GNU-screen and org-mode (and also of Emacs, of course) for there to be a widely accepted solution to this problem.

Comment: "...widely accepted solution..." I like your optimism.

Comment: I use tmux, so I'm not sure if the keybinding also works on screen, but I use M-0 (Alt-zero). 
I chose the character since its a numeric prefix, but there is hardly ever a reason to use 0 as a prefix, and in any case C-0 would work in the same manner

Comment: Related: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GnuScreen

Answer (score 6):

Not sure how widely accepted this is, but <kbd>C-z</kbd> works reasonably well. By default in emacs that is bound to `suspend-frame`, and shell uses it for suspend/background task. Emacs also binds <kbd>C-x C-z</kbd> to `suspend-frame` so there is another binding anyway. If `escape ^Zz` is set for screen, <kbd>C-z z</kbd> will send a <kbd>C-z</kbd> to the nested process to background.

This also works for tmux with

```
set -g prefix C-z                                                                                         
unbind C-b                                                                                                
bind C-z send-prefix
```

For tmux this means sending <kbd>C-z</kbd> to a nested application can be accomplished with <kbd>C-z C-z</kbd>.

Some additional reasons why <kbd>C-z</kbd> is a good idea:

- suspend is a means of multi-tasking in a single shell session, whereas default workflow in screen/tmux is to open a new nested shell.
- suspend is still available but only one extra keystroke away (which befits the frequency of it's use for my workflow)
- It's an easy single hand binding (which might not be great for RSI) but makes it easier to use one-handed (if eating or mostly reading).
- In most other contexts it's bound to `undo`.

Comment: C-z is a great solution not just for screen, but also tmux -- perhaps could even become a "widely accepted solution."

Comment: `C-z` is very useful to put Emacs in the background. I use `C-o` as my control character. It's not perfect, it coincides with `open-line`, but I don't use that as often.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>C-j</kbd> is rarely used inside or outside Emacs, and it's right on the home row.

Answer (score 0):

`C-b` is only used for `backward-char`.

Comment: Yes this is a reasonable compromise if the C-z solution as proposed by dgtized is not possible for some reason.